# MSI U130 freezes on shutdown

Tags: 10.10, shutdown, freeze, acpi, ralink

The computer freezes when i shutdown. I have tried  the ACPI options `acpi=off` and `acpi=force` but they don't work.

The computer is a MSI U130. The only way to shutdown is by long pressing the power button. It is running Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10.

Wifi: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally fixed it it was a problem with the wifi driver all I had to do is this:

Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (as root) and add at the end:

```
blacklist rt2800pci
```

The problem has that there was a wrong driver loaded.

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion??

Comment: I'd like to know too because I am having a similar problem.

Comment: After disabling that driver, so which driver are you using?